# How to use the result of this method?

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I'm developing in AS3 for the Doubleclick platform, though this may be more of a generic programming question.

I am trying to determine whether a video is playing or paused. Doubleclick has the following method:

videoController.getPlayerState()

Which when traced, returns either:

[object PlayingState]

or

[object PausedState]

My question is, how do I do work with that result? I just want to turn it into a boolean that I can use in an if statement to call, or not call, another function.

Like:

if([object PlayingState]){ doSomething(); } else {doNothing(); }

Except that you can't do that, because whenever I try to do anything like that I get an error!! And I can't figure out how you're supposed to do this.

I'm sure this is super-basic. Can anyone enlighten me??

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this doc [PlayingState](http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/sdk/flash/as3/en/com_google_ads_studio_video_PlayingState.html)

The PlayingState and PausedState class extends AbstractPlayerState,

And AbstractPlayerState get a function getStateType said like this

```
getStateType() : String
     Returns the player state as a string such as "InitialState","BufferingState",
     "LoadingState", "PausedState", "PlayingState", or "StoppedState".
     It is encouraged to use videoController.getPlayerState() and match against the 
     relevant class using instanceof or is.
```

So I think you can do like this

```
var state:AbstractPlayerState  = videoController.getPlayerState();

if (state is PlayingState) {

} else if ( state is PausedState) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sending me to that doc! I was able to see that you can actually pass a value of true into the play method, which negates the need to check for whether the video is playing or not, because "true" always pauses the video. Sorry I don't have enough points to upvote your answer!